# How could I match a list of numbers in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe of where one of the columns contains numerical values which correspond to the row number of another dataframe. How would I get the row names of the dataframe using the numbers contained in the first dataframe.

I know you could do this manually by doing:

```
rownames_of_matrix <- rownames(second_matrix[c( 1, 2 , 3 numbers in
                                                1st dataframe ),])
```

but I would like to know if there's a way I can do this without manually pasting the numbers across because it is a very large dataframe and it would be quite cumbersome and be a big chunk of text.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe use `second_matrix[first_matrix[, column], ]`, where `column` is the column name/number that contains the data you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 a= data.frame(nam=c(3,2,5,6),f=1:4,g=2:5)  # 'a$nam' contains row names of df
 a
   nam f g
 1   3 1 2
 2   2 2 3
 3   5 3 4
 4   6 4 5

 df <- data.frame(a=41:40,b=11:20,c=21:30)  # 'df' data frame
 df
     a  b  c
 1  41 11 21
 2  40 12 22
 3  41 13 23
 4  40 14 24
 5  41 15 25
 6  40 16 26
 7  41 17 27
 8  40 18 28
 9  41 19 29
 10 40 20 30


 df[a$nam,]             # Extracting row names contained in 'a$nam' column in 'a' from 'df'
    a  b  c
 3 41 13 23
 2 40 12 22
 5 41 15 25
 6 40 16 26
```